# jQuery clone api doesn't clone the native javascript events

Tags: jquery, events, clone, native

If I add a native event handler to an element using the "element.onclick = function() {...};" syntax, and later I clone the element with the jQuery clone api, using 'true' parameter, then the cloned element doesn't get the natively added event handler. How can I solve it, if the native syntax that I've used above is a must (so pls don't give me an answer like "use $(element).click(function(e){...});", etc..).

In code:

EDIT: pls check on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86f96/

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for this, so we can take a look at the full code and HTML? It's always easier this way, to see if nothing else affects the JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 elements with the ID `btn` on the same page.

EDIT:

I looked at the jsfiddle, and sadly I can't come up with a different solution, other than attaching the click event again, after appending the `clone`

EDIT 2:

This is as close as I got, without changing the native JS `onclick` event. So if for some reason, you can't change the previously defined function, this would help:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function() { alert( 'clicked' ); };
//...
var clone = $(element).clone(true);
var native_click_function = $(element)[0].onclick;
$(element).remove();
clone.appendTo('body').click(function(){
    native_click_function();
});
```

The code is taken from the JS fiddle.

Comment: Yes I know, this is only a dummy code. I remove the original element before append the clone.

Comment: This advice has given me an idea to solve the problem, but I have to work more abstractly. Maybe I'll override the clone api, and walk trough all the possible native events. So thx, you've brought me closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

append and appendTo don't pass the events. Some see it as a bug, some see it as a feature, alas the only way around it is to use live() or redefine the events.

Comment: I've used the clone in the same way, but it doesn't work as I've written in the description. clone(true) works only for jQuery events, those are stored in the jQuery data.

Comment: Sorry I wrote that answer befor ereading the jsfiddle code properly.